# What is the difference between BeanPostProcessor and init/destroy method in Spring?

Tags: spring

What is the difference between implementing the `BeanPostProcessor` interface and either using the `init`/`destroy` method attributes in the XML configuration file in Spring or implementing `InitializingBean`/`DisposableBean` interface?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This is pretty clearly explained in the Spring documentation about the [Container Extension Points](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp).

> The BeanPostProcessor interface defines callback methods that you can
>   implement to provide your own (or override the container's default)
>   instantiation logic, dependency-resolution logic, and so forth. If you
>   want to implement some custom logic after the Spring container
>   finishes instantiating, configuring, and initializing a bean, you can
>   plug in one or more BeanPostProcessor implementations.

So in essence the method `postProcessBeforeInitialization` defined in the BeanPostProcessor gets called (as the name indicates) before the initialization of beans and likewise the `postProcessAfterInitialization` gets called after the initialization of the bean.

The difference to the `@PostConstruct`, `InitializingBean` and custom `init` method is that these are defined on the bean itself. Their ordering can be found in the [Combining lifecycle mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-combined-effects) section of the spring documentation.

**So basically the BeanPostProcessor can be used to do custom instantiation logic for several beans wheras the others are defined on a per bean basis.**

Answer (score 19):

Above answers clearly explains some of the very important aspect.

Apart from that it's also important to understand that both beanPostProcessor and init and destroy methods are part of the Spring bean life cycle.

BeanPostProcessor class has two methods.

1) postProcessBeforeInitialization - as name clearly says that it's used to make sure required actions are taken before initialization. e.g. you want to load certain property file/read data from the remote source/service.

2) postProcessAfterInitialization - any thing that you want to do after initialization before bean reference is given to application.

Sequence of the questioned methods in life cycle as follows :

1) BeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization()

2) init()

3) BeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization()

4) destroy()

You may check this by writing simple example having sysout and check their sequence.

Answer (score 8):

**Init and Destroy callback methods** are part of Spring bean life cycle phases. The *init* method is going to be executed after bean instantiation. Similarly, The *destroy* method is going to be executed before bean finalization.

We can implement this functionality using implementing interfaces `InitializingBean` and `DisposableBean`, or using annotations `@postconstruct` and `@predestroy`, or declare the `<bean>` with `init-method` and `destroy-method` attributes.

**BeanPostProcessor interface** is used for extending the functionality of framework if want to do any configuration Pre- and Post- bean initialization done by spring container.

**For Example**: By default, Spring will not aware of the `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotation. To enable it, we have to either register `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` or specify the `<context:annotation-config />` in bean configuration file. Here `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is predefined `BeanPostProcessor` implementation for the annotations. Like:

**@Required** enables  `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`  processing tool
**@Autowired** enables  `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` processing tool

Answer (score 6):

And one more main diff is InitializingBean,DisposableBean related afterPropertiesSet() & destory() methods did not accept any paratmeters and return type also void, so we did not implement any custom logic.
But coming to BeanPostProcess methods postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean,String beanName) and postProcessAfterInitilization(Object bean,String beanName) are accept those two paramaters and return type also Object so we are able to write initilzation logics as well as any custom login based on the passing bean...

These both callback method feautes are including the bean life cycle and the following are the life cycle as follows

1) BeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitilazation()

2) @postConstruct or InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet() or initialization method which is
   defining in xml    /***  here also it's following the same oredr if three ways are availiable **/

3) BeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization()

4) @preDestroy or DisposibleBean.destroy() or destroy method which is defining in xml
     /***  here also it's following the same oredr if three ways are availiable **/

Answer (score 2):

Just a short supplement to all the answers above:  If you have any generic logic, common logic that needs to be universally applied to all your Spring beans, such as the injection of a logger to your beans, setting of a properties file, setting default values to fields of your beans through reflection; you could put that logic into ONE single place: the `@Override`n callbacks (eg: `postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object arg0, String arg1)` if you are implementing the `BeanPostProcessor` interface); instead of duplicating the same logic across all your beans.

Answer (score -1):

a)The postProcessBeforeInitialization() will be called before initialization of the bean.

b)Once the bean gets initialized, the different callbacks methods are called in the following order as per the Spring docs:

1. Methods annotated with @PostConstruct
2. afterPropertiesSet() as defined by the InitializingBean callback interface
3. init method defined through the XML.

The main difference is that the above 3 methods get called after the initialization get completed by the postProcessBeforeInitialization() method.

Once these methods get completed the method postProcessAfterInitialization() will be called and then the destroy methods are called in the same order:

1. Methods annotated with @PreDestroy
2. destroy() as defined by the DisposableBean callback interface
3. destroy() method defined through the XML.